# xcode UIView ScaleAspectFit for UITextfield setLeftView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimage, uitextfield

I'd like to have an icon in my textfield and I'm using a the setLeftView attribute. 
my code at the moment is

```
    UIView *leftView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 26, tb_teamA_playerA.bounds.size.height)];
    leftView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [leftView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed : @"person_26" ]]];
    [tb_teamA_playerA setLeftView :leftView];
    [tb_teamA_playerA setLeftViewMode: UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
```

that's the result.

[image]

the very left image is a separate UIImageView with the same image set and the scale set to ScaleAspectFit.
So I was expecting the two images to be the same size and scale but they are not?!

Answer (score 2):

You are using UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit, so the image will fit the size of the UITextField.
I think you should use UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill, and if you have some problem with ths size and the two images still don't have the same size, you should resize you image.

The following is from the [Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIViewContentMode)

**UIViewContentModeScaleToFill**

> Scales the content to fit the size of itself by changing the aspect ratio of the content if necessary.

**UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit**

> Scales the content to fit the size of the view by maintaining the aspect ratio. Any remaining area of the view’s bounds is transparent.

**UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill**

> Scales the content to fill the size of the view. Some portion of the content may be clipped to fill the view’s bounds.